# A COUNT on a CASE Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm editng my original request as I think i've confused myself as well as others.  I want to do a count of incidents within the Continents. Sorry for the confusion

```
ID,  --a unique incident number

case 
when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('France','UK',Germany) then 'Europe'
when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('Argentina','Peru','Brazil') 
then 'SouthAmerica'      
when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('Bangladesh,'India','China') 
then 'Asia'      
end as "Continent"
```

This is what I would like to see

```
      Continent      Total           
       Europe          15
       Asia            12
       Asia             9
       SouthAmerica     5
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You say "COUNT on the continent". Bangladesh and India are both Asia, but have different numbers, so do you mean count by country?

Comment: sorry I omitted an important part from this, I have an 'Incident'  column which gives a unique ID every time there's an incident. So i'm counting the number of incidents in each continent

Comment: So how come Bangladesh and India have different numbers? Same continent...

Answer (score 3):

Postgres allow you to use the table alias in the `group by`, so you can do:

```
select cs.country,
       (case when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('France', 'UK', Germany) 
             then 'Europe'
             when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('Argentina', 'Peru', 'Brazil') 
             then 'SouthAmerica'      
             when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('Bangladesh', 'India', 'China') 
             then 'Asia'      
        end) as Continent,
       count(*)
from t
group by country, continent;
```

However, you need to be careful, because if there is a column called `continent` in your table, then the `group by` will use that instead.

Also, you really should have a reference table that looks up the continent.  Blocks of code like this tend to become a maintenance nightmare, as they get copied into new queries over time.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your original query up as a derived table. Then `GROUP BY` it's result:

```
select Country, "Continent", count(*)
from
(
  select
  cs.country,
  case 
  when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('France','UK',Germany) then 'Europe'
  when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('Argentina','Peru','Brazil') 
  then 'SouthAmerica'      
  when trim(both ' ' from cs.country) in ('Bangladesh,'India','China') 
  then 'Asia'      
  end as "Continent"
  from tablename
)
group by Country, "Continent"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

As @GordonLinoff pointed out you really want a table, here I make a table in-line using the values statement.  Then when you want to materialize the table almost no changes to your query are needed.

Also, it may be the case, a join like this will run faster than a CASE statement... depends on many things -- but I've see it happen.

```
select cs.country, coalesce(tmp.con, 'unknown') as continent, count(*)
from t cs
left join (
   values
     ('France', 'Europe'),
     ('UK', 'Europe'),
     ('Germany', 'Europe'),
     ('Argentina', 'SouthAmerica'),
     ('Peru', 'SouthAmerica'),
     ('Brazil', 'SouthAmerica'),
     ('Bangladesh', 'Asia'),
     ('India', 'Asia'),
     ('China', 'Asia')
) as tmp(cou,con) ON cou = trim(both ' ' from cs.country)
groupby cs.country, coalesce(tmp.con, 'unknown')
```